# Will the rooting method I previously used with my Nvidia Shield Tablet work with the new update?

Tags: rooting, 5.1-lollipop, nvidia-shield

I'll soon be getting a replacement for my Shield Tablet due to the recall.

I used a rooting method that used ADB and Fastboot to unlock the bootloader, flash CWM, then flash SuperSU and root.

It worked with Android 5.0.1, shield update 2.2, but the new tablet will most likely be on update 3.1, Android 5.1.

So I ask - will the rooting method and all of the files linked to in the guide (which I will link to down below) work with the new setup?

Guide I used: http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/how-root-nvidia-shield-tablet-android-5-0-lollipop-install-cwm-recovery-1481041

Answer (score 0):

Your original rooting method will work. The bootloader is still unlockable on the replacement devices, just as it was on the original ones. The fact that it is running a newer version of Android doesn't really have any meaningful bearing on this since SuperSU is still actively developed to ensure compatibility with newer Android builds.

Comment: But will the version of CWM that is linked to on the guide still work?

Comment: @G12350 Actively follow CWM development. You would get the build if somebody creates it. Also, look for other custom recoveries as well. Besides, you don't have the device or the ROM at hand, so why bother this much. Simply exercise patience.

Comment: @G12350 Nothing has changed that would cause the recovery to suddenly stop working. Again, the version of Android you happen to be running has practically no bearing on that.

Comment: Installing CWM didn't work. I flashed the recovery image but when I went into the recovery I got and android with a red triangle, holding up and lock brought me to the default recovery.